# How to receive MYSQL warnings (E.g. #1264 Out of Range) from PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, error-handling, warnings

while I am working with PHP PDO I noticed that I can change the ERROR MODE to Exceptions.

**But what if I need to know the MYSQL WARNINGS as well.**

Example:

```
update <table> SET number = 99999999999
```

should cause MYSQL to throw the below warning when **number** is an **int(11)**

```
Warning: #1264 Out of range value for column 'number' at row 1
```

To keep my data consistent between the application and MYSQL I would like to catch it

A possible workaround is to validate the input through PHP. But thats not what I am searching for.

Thank you in advance,
Ole

Comment: `SHOW WARNINGS` this can help you

Comment: read this:http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: @SuchitKumar as I wrote already I know error handling and I do not want to change it to any other than Exceptions

Comment: @Vicky your comment helped me alot - if its ok with you I will add this as answer

Comment: @OleK no issues!! you can add anywhere and i am upvoting ur answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Vicky,

possible solutions is to do a MYSQL query on "SHOW WARNINGS"

Example:

```
$warnings = $this->PDO->query("SHOW WARNINGS")->fetchObject();
// example output of $warnings OR NULL
// stdClass Object
// (
//        [Level] => Warning
//        [Code] => 1264
//        [Message] => Out of range value for column 'qty' at row 1 
// }
```